Name of a horror action movie, probably 90's or 80's?
I saw it when I was a child, it starts with a woman running away from a bike gang, but they rape and kill her. After some years, a new group of bikers visits the town, the same woman seduces them and kills the boys while having sex. She also kills his girls in same way, having sex in a haunted house. At the end, the ghosts-demon/woman has sex with the protagonist, but his girlfriend saves him and kills the ghost-demon woman. 
That is all I can remember. I saw it in the early 2000's on TV, but it was an older movie. The distinctive part of the movie was that the ghost woman seduces the girls and the boys with her ghost power, laughs "hahaha" and then kills them because she was raped and killed by bikers.

Hellgate (1989)

In 1957 a group of bikers lead by two men named Buzz (Frank Notard) and Zonk (Lance Vaughan) cause trouble with some locals at a diner and kidnap as well as rape one of the customers there named Josie (Abigail Wolcott) in which they murder her in a town called Hellgate too leaving her old eccentric father Lucas (Carel Trichardt) in misery and alone but a townsfolk named Nervous Norman (Jonathan Taylor) finds a crystal like object that zaps dead things to life and Lucas uses this to resurrect his daughter during present day and filled Hell Gate with re-animated corpses in which they were victims seduced by Josie who is now a beuatiful zombie herself.
  She spots a man she is in awe with named Matt (Ron Palillo) who she finds the final object of her desire wanting to spend etenrity with him in bed but her father wants him dead.

